# Mutual TLS at the application level with OpenSSL

Tags: node.js, openssl, tls1.2, mtls

I have a Node.js server that receives a request with the Client TLS certificate supplied in the [XFCC](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-forwarded-client-cert) header.

I would like to perform the Mutual TLS at the Application level, i.e. validate Client TLS cert against the server's CA truststore - all of this done in application code, rather than relying on a web proxy configuration.

I am using NPM's [pem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pem) dependency, which is essentially a bunch of JS wrappers around `openssl`. In particular, the verification needed to resemble mTLS is the `verify` method:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /my/server/ca-chain.crt client-chain.crt
```

This works in the simplest case:

- ca-chain.crt: `Root CA` -> `Int 1 CA`
- client-chain.crt `Root CA` -> `Int 1 CA` -> `Leaf 1`

But it fails in the more complex cases where Int CA's are different:

- ca-chain.crt: `Root CA` -> `Int 1 CA`
- client-chain.crt `Root CA` -> `Int 2 CA` -> `Leaf 2`

With the following:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /my/server/ca-chain.crt client-chain.crt
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

As far as I understand mTLS would be successfully performed as long as all certs are valid and lead up to the **same** `Root CA`, despite different `Int CA`'s, which means `verify` doesn't work as-is for the purpose of doing mTLS equivalent at the App level.

I know about `s_client` and `s_server` capabilities, but they seem like hacks for what I need, rather than a proper solution.

I guess my question is then this:

- Is it possible to use `openssl` to verify certificate against CA chain according to the mTLS rules?
- And if not possible, then what would be the way to do it without resorting to writing it from scratch?

Comment: @user207421 IDK even where to begin to address such a hostile comment, but it's not as unusual as you think, and in fact, some of the very well-known solutions perform mTLS at the application level. Check out how Kong does it, for example.

Comment: Also: `verify that the identity established by the authenticated client certificate is authorized to access this part of your application` -

Well, in my case the application itself *is* the Auth server, and its sole responsibility is to do such verification. However it sits behind the L7 API Gateway, and there is no simple way to pass through the underlying TLS cert except for the header.

Comment: Not visibly about programming or development, and **dupe** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204616/why-does-openssl-verify-fail-with-a-certificate-chain-file- and several more linked there (by me), mostly in security.SX where they belong.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I wouldn't necessarily agree it's not a programming question since it is in the scope of Node.js and it's module `pem` - for example, one of the suggestions could've been to resort to the usage of the different module. However, you're right that one of your SO answers might contain what I need, specifically this one very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375300/openssl-verify-with-chained-ca-and-chained-cert. I am going to take a look and then resolve this question, if it works afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) pointed out in his [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375300/openssl-verify-with-chained-ca-and-chained-cert), for the `openssl verify` to make it work you need to be aware that **it does not read the entire certificate chain from the supplied client cert file, only the last (leaf) certificate**.

So I believe that [this method](https://dexus.github.io/pem/jsdoc/pem.js.html#line940) in `pem` package is not entirely correct (in fact they do have [open issue](https://github.com/Dexus/pem/issues/303) on that), but that's another thing for discussion.

The supposed `openssl` command should've been translated to is this:

```sh
openssl verify -CAfile /my/server/ca-chain.crt -untrusted client-ca-chain.crt client-leaf.crt
```

Here I split the leaf client cert from the rest of the chain which is passed in the `-untrusted` param, while `-CAfile` contains a chain with different a `Int CA`, but which eventually leads up to the same `Root CA` - and this is what effectively makes the client cert chain valid.

This should be fairly trivial to implement with the Node.js' [openssl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openssl-nodejs) or similar wrapper.